# Rails - change column name in model for MS SQL server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, activerecord

I have to use Rails with an existing MSSQL DB.
I have created two models - Order and Items and created association between them (1 to many)

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base   
  self.table_name  = 'mobile_orders'
  has_many :items  
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base    
  self.table_name  = 'mobile_items'
  belongs_to :order 
end
```

In mobile_items table I have a column named 'order_no'.
I tried to check the association in Rails but when I do this:

```
order = Order.last
order.items
```

the adapter is running query looking for 'order_id' (when my column name is 'order_no'), e.g:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [mobile_items].* FROM [mobile_items] WHERE [mobile_items].[order_id] = @0', N'@0 int', @0 = 9  [["order_id", 9]]
```

Is there a way to to use 'order_no' for this query?
I have tried this in Order model but no luck:

```
alias_attribute :order_id, :order_no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can specify the `foreign_key` option:

```
belongs_to :order, foreign_key: :order_no
```

Look for `foreign_key` option in [Giudes on belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) and [Associations docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: no, still the same - TinyTds::Error: Invalid column name 'order_id'.

Please note that I'm using
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.2.0'
for MS SQL connection

Comment: @82skynet what is used for primary keys, `id` or something else?

Comment: it's 'id' for both tables. 'order_no' is just a normal column

Comment: it worked but I had to specify the foreign_key option in Order model:
has_many :items, foreign_key: :order_no